# Adding image to Pdf file using Itext Pdf

Tags: java, spring, pdf, itext

I am using iText to generate Pdf. But when I'm trying to add images in the pdf,

`Image schoolLogo = Image.getInstance(new URL(timetableResource.getImageUrl())); 
document.add(schoolLogo);`

But I'm getting error as

> HTTP Status 500 - Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://139.59.72.150:8080/sms/attachments/23/42/school/23/23/Vandana International School Logo.png
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:(myUrl)
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: (myUrl)
>       sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
>       sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>       java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
>       com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: `400 for URL (myUrl)` somewhere you have incorrect URL

Comment: I see that you are using a version of iText that can no longer be used: [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) How do I know? Because I see my name in your error message.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider switching to iText7. As Bruno already indicated, you are currently using a version that is no longer supported.
For your information, the iText7 way of adding an image would be:

```
String FOX = "path/to/resource/fox.png";
String DOG = "path/to/resource/dog.png";

Image fox = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(FOX));
Image dog = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(DOG));
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("The quick brown ")
                .add(fox)
                .add(" jumps over the lazy ")
                .add(dog);
document.add(p);
```

There a complete jumpstart tutorial, aimed at those people who already know how iText works and need some pointers migrating to iText7.

Check it out at http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks

Comment: That's true, but that won't solve the problem caused by the fact that (1.) the URL isn't valid, (2.) the resource isn't availabe, (3.) the Tomcat instance that serves the image returns an HTML page with an error message,...

Comment: I would argue that in all of those instances, it is not really an iText problem. Garbage (bad url) in, garbage out.

Comment: Of course it's not an iText issue. It's a bad question that should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

400 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#HTTP_BAD_REQUEST

obviously is a error of connection, check if url is valid please and you can do log in normally.

Comment: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: I must have 50 reputation to comment :'(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, the problem is with the spaces in the url. I have replaced the blank spaces with '%20' and it working perfectly fine.